# Integral and differential inequality

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, integral-inequality, stability-in-odes

I have integral and differential inequality

$y'(t)<Ch^{k+1}+\int_0^ty(s)ds+y(t)$

where $C,h$ are constants and $y$ is positive function with y(0)=0

My goal is to prove

$y(t_F)<Ch^{k+1}$
where $t_F$ is final time

Is it possible? At first, I misread the equation as without integration. At that time, Gronwall's inequality was enough. However, becaus of that integration on the right hand side, I don't know how to prove this anymore.

Is there any theorem for such integral differential inequality?